# Grabbing storeview from cookie (after using language selector)

Tags: php, session, cookie

I have written a custom function to set our MAGERUNCODE based on the accept language and the uri request (beeing /). THis works fine.

Now I have 1 remaining issue. And this is when the customer uses the store switcher and 'forces' to see another language. I understand that the request storeview is then stored in a COOKIE.

**Question**: how can I grab the storeview from te Magento cookie (after the language switcher was used)

Many thanks, Sean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128412/how-to-extract-some-value-from-cookie-in-nginx

Comment: if ($http_cookie ~ 'NAME=VALUE') {
        ACTION
        };

Comment: or use map module the same way, to map cookie values to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the code like below. If the root (/) is requested and a store cookie was not already set, then run `getLanguageRunCode` and try to find a store matching your language.

The store cookie is acquired through `Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('store')`

```
Mage::init();
$_storecookie = empty(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('store'));
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/' && $_storecookie) {
  $mageRunCode = getLanguageRunCode($mageRunCode);
}
```